# How does one go about proving that certain number is not a period?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

If one takes the following definition: "A period is a number that can be expressed as an integral of an algebraic function over an algebraic domain", how could one go about determining that a certain number, say $\exp(\pi)$ (but I'm not interested in this concrete example), is not a period?

Since I can think of only one way how one could prove that a number is a period - by constructing an integral with the aforementioned properties - the possible way of proving the converse seems impossible for me. But I am missing something, am I not?

UPD: the context is that I was reading paper "Periods" by Maxim Kontsevich and Don Zagier and didn't find any information about how to prove that a number is not a period.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the source is missing, and quite some context.

Comment: I've heard in a seminar that noncomputable numbers are counterexamples, but I am unfamiliar with the proof.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that non-computable numbers are counterexamples — given the definition of a period one can in principle compute it to any degree of accuracy using any of the normal techniques, and in fact I believe it's even possible to get upper and lower bounds by using interval arithmetic; that's enough to get a 'computation' of the value of the period by any reasonable definition thereof I know.

Comment: Concretely, I believe this is a Hard Problem — AFAIK all the results about various classic numbers _not_ being periods are conjectural.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki so the impression that one simply looks for an integral for long enough time and then comes up with a conjecture that the number is not a period?

Comment: Well, there are more reasons than just 'we can't show they are' to believe that some numbers aren't periods. For a rather complicated discussion, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20497/is-it-known-that-the-ring-of-periods-is-not-a-field . https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20430/is-there-an-explicit-example-of-a-complex-number-which-is-not-a-period is another slightly friendlier reference.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki aha, yes, that actually should be helpful because I started reading Don Zagier and Kontsevich to get something about motives. Thanks!